# What is wrong with this PHP regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

```
$output = preg_replace("|(/D)(/s+)(/d+)(;)|", "//1,//3;", $output);
```

I'm trying to replace all alphabetical character followed by one or more whitespace characters (tabs and/or spaces) followed by one or more numerical characters followed by a semicolon with the alphabetical character followed by a comma followed by the numerical digits and then the semicolon.

I'll provide an example:

Start:

```
hello world      1007;
```

End:

```
hello world,1007;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two `|` at the start and end probably are incorrect - and should both be forward-slashes.

All other forward slashes should be backward slashes (and need escaping).

And since PHP 4.04 `$n` is the preferred way of referring to a capture group.

```
$output = preg_replace("/(\\D)\\s+(\\d+;)/", "$1,$2", $output);
```

If you use single quotes you don't need to escape your backslashes:

```
$output = preg_replace('/(\D)\s+(\d+;)/', '$1,$2', $output);
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, the start- and end-of-pattern symbols (the '|'s) are required in the PHP preg_* functions.

Answer (score 3):

Should those forward-slashes be backslashes? You'll need to escape them for PHP too unless you change your double-quotes to single-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You want backslashes in the regular expression, not forward slashes.  The starting and ending pipes **are** needed (or another delimiter for the regex)

```
$x = "hello world      1007;";    
echo preg_replace('|(\D)(\s+)(\d+)(;)|','$1,$3',$x);
echo preg_replace('/(\D)(\s+)(\d+)(;)/','$1,$3',$x);
echo preg_replace('{(\D)(\s+)(\d+)(;)}','$1,$3',$x);
```